# Flutter - Is there an effect on having a single import rather than multiple?

Tags: dart

Basically I have a lot of widgets and services and stuff, like most people do, that I need to access throughout the app. I was wondering if have a single file with an export of every single file and then just simply importing that one file in every page/file i need to access something rather than just importing specific files that the page needs, will it slow down the app or cause any issues or increase file size, etc... or will it behave the same?

Example

login_page.dart

```
import '1.dart'
import '2.dart'
```

home_page.dart

```
import '2.dart'
import '3.dart'
import '9.dart'
import '10.dart'
```

settings_page.dart

```
import '1.dart'
import '2.dart'
import '9.dart'
import '10.dart'
```

or...

all_imports.dart:

```
export '1.dart'
export '2.dart'
export '3.dart'
... (up until)
export '10.dart'
```

in every dart file:

```
import 'all_imports.dart'
```

Comment: sir, any upadate on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using 'all_imports.dart' may cause unneeded dependencies but dart knows how to handle dependencies that called but not used.

Same implementation of 'all_imports.dart' is used by flutter team on 'material.dart'

You may wish to just make simple design but when you import 'material.dart' it brings everything to the table ('about.dart', 'app.dart', 'banner.dart') and many others.

I would advise you structure your application using 'all_import.dart' pattern

Answer (score 2):

actually, it dosent make a difference, lets imagine this case

in `login_page.dart`

```
import '1.dart'
import '2.dart'
```

here you are being explicit about the dependencies of this module/file/widget, which means it only uses what it needs. which is better for maintenance and redablity of the modules dependanices.

the other case where you have all of your imports in one file

```dart
import 'all_imports.dart'
```

lets see what happens here:

1. Dart executes the file `all_imports.dart`
2. that file is importing every module that you have listed in that file
3. so the import calls happend again

which means that wont affect your software's performance if you dont have an `all_imports.dart` file. 
actulally i find that this method(the `all_imports.dart`) will affect your program in a bad way if any.

---

**why?** lets say we have a **module A** that depends on both **module B** and **module C** , you would import them this way

`moduleA.dart`

```
import 'moduleB'
import 'moduleC'
```

- the advantages is that the module is now explicit in its dependencies and anyone who looks at this module/file in the future will know what they are.

### however

the other method where you have all of your imports in a single `all_imports.dart` file, will cause unneeded dependencies to be loaded for a certain module

---

lets have the same example above, **module A** depends on **moduleB** and **moduleC** and you listed them in the `all_imports.dart` file, it will look like this

```
export `moduleA'
export 'moduleB'

/// some other modules that you are exporting
```

and in the `moduleA.dart` file you import it this way

```
import 'all_imports.dart`
```

now

the module A has successfully imported moduleB and moduleC which it needs. **BUT**, now it has all the other dependancies that it dose not need loaded for it although it only needs moduleA and moduleB.

Comment: As I understood, dart will make up for this and it will not effect your performance.